# Describe the null space and the range of $T$

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation such that
$$ T(1,0,0)=(1,-2) \text , \quad T(0,1,0)=(-2,4) \text , \quad \text { and } T(0,0,1)=(3,-6) \text . $$

I found the null space which is $\operatorname{N}(T)=\langle (2,1,0) , (-3,0,1) \rangle$. But I'm confused between two answers for the range of $T$ ,the first one is $(-1,2)$, and the second is $(-1,2,3)$.

Comment: The range is, by definition, a subset of the codomain. The codomain is the thing at the right end of the arrow; in this case, it's the set of all ordered pairs of reals. $(-1,2,3)$ is not an ordered pair of reals, so it can't be in the range. But also the range is a set, not a single point, so it can't be $(-1,2)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so what is the range of T

Comment: The range of $T$ is the *span* of $\{(-1,2)\}$.

Comment: Do you understand now, udhdhd? Do you perhaps want to "accept" the answer from @Mohammad by clicking in the check mark next to it? Or is there something you're still uncertain about?

Comment: Are you still here, udhdhd?

Answer (score 1):

The range of your transformation is the line $$y=-2x$$ and the null space is the plane $$x-2y+3z=0$$
Both results are clear when you find the matrix of the transformation whose columns are respectively $$<1,-2>^T,<-2,4>^T, and <3,-6>^T$$

Comment: hello mohammad i really appreciate that you spend time for solving it, just quick question how did you achieve that y=-2x is the range of T , and one more question how do i write it as a vector

Comment: If you look at the vectors (1,-2), (-2,4), and (3,-6) which span the range, you notice that the second component is -2 times the first component, that is y=-2x.  As a vector you may write it as (t, -2t).